# How to use SQL Server Database Project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I am running SQL Server 2012 and VS 2010 with SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) installed. My dev DB uses stored procs, functions, CLR objects, etc. It has a snapshot of prod data of about 500GB.

I created SQL Server Database Project and then imported the database. This created all tables, views, procs and functions files under schema names. Great stuff -- now I can do a version control just like in other VS projects, create deployments, etc. So far, so good.

But, I am confused as to what my development process should be for changing/adding procs/tables under SQL Server Database Project. It appears that any changes I make are applied to some LocalDb/Projects database and NOT to my dev database.

Am I suppose to author all my objects in that LocalDb, then Build and deploy to my dev database via Publish? I am worried about my existing tables in the dev DB since if the publish process drops and recreates tables, I will loose my prod data snapshot.

What is the right development process to follow in SQL Server Database Project?

Comment: You can configure to which DB that DBPROJ deploys to. It will warn you if it can't make a 'breaking' change, i.e. one which would require dropping of a table and loss of data. You also have the option to generate a change script, instead of directly changing DDL - this gives you the option of viewing the changes.

Comment: Is nobody using SSDT to develop stored procedures / views / funcitons? Because I have got to believe there is a better answer than re-publish and "try it."  Maybe Unit Tests are what Microsoft Intended us to use?  What are other users doing?

Answer (score 6):

Think of the source database (in your case, your database project) as being the "to be" state after deployment. When a deployment is initiated, the executable (SqlPackage.exe) compares the source with the target and generates a difference/delta script to make the target look like the source. This is why we no longer have to specify `CREATE` or `ALTER`; the tool figures it out. To answer your question about ongoing development, you can develop either way. You can develop in the project files and publish them to a common Dev database (say, if you're on a team), or you can develop in the database with tools like SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and synchronize with the project files with a schema compare (I use the latter technique because I like SSMS).

For deployment, you'll have to have SSDT installed on the machine from which you execute the deployment (SSDT ships with SQL Server 2012 and later; I don't know about SQL Server 2008). You can create scripts to simplify deployment. You'll essentially call SqlPackage.exe (it lives in x:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\DAC\bin) with an action and a source. I use Publish Profiles as well to take care of most command properties. So an example deployment might look like this:

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:MyDatabase.dacpac /Profile:MyProfile.publish.xml
```

For more information:
SQL Server Data Tools Documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx

SqlPackage.exe Documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: I guess the part I'm missing is the "Develop in the database with tool like SSMS" - what does that look like when using a DB Project? I'm used to having my script files with a `IF EXISTS...DROP...` at the top and `GO ... EXEC SprocName @params` ... at the bottom.  So I can edit the sproc, hit F5, and see the new results.  But if I save that file to DB project, it will complain because it ONLY wants the CREATE statement. I don't want to manually set that up each time I make a little change to sproc.  What does the process of making/testing a change to a sproc/view look like for you?

Comment: One of the first things to learn about SSDT, as with any tool, is its view of the world. As I said in my post, SSDT sees the /SourceFile parameter as the state that the target database must be in at the end of the deployment. And to get there, it generates a delta script, based on comparing the target to the source, to make that happen. If your stored procedure does not yet exist in the target, it generates a CREATE PROCEDURE statement to create it; otherwise, it generates an ALTER PROCEDURE statement to update it.

Comment: By "Develop in the database with tool like SSMS" I mean to use SSMS to write your stored procedures as we've traditionally done. Since you're working directly with with the database objects, you'll need to use CREATE/ALTER accordingly. When you're done, go back to the Database project and use a Schema Compare to synchronize the new or updated stored procedure with code in the Database project.

Comment: Thanks Craig - I'll give you the bounty because I think this is going to lead to my final solution.  I'll post it as an answer if it ends up working well.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make changes inside the VS DB project.
2. Deploy changes to localDB to test
3. Publish the database to your production server. I prefer to use Schema Compare to do this manually, but you can also publish the project via the right click --> publish menu (which will also create a publishing profile), or using command line arguments. The publish process won't drop and create tables (unless you tell it to drop & recreate the entire db).

Alternatively, in the project settings you can change the connection string to point to your production server (as pointed out in the comment). However, I recommend against this, as it will then attempt to publish to the production server every time you run a local build (F5).