# Clone an empty database to server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want deploy a C#.Net application which have MS SQL database. I want programmatically create new database (including tables, views, stored procedure etc. and some fixed values in table) with client given name.  Can you suggest better method? Or simply I want clone an empty database to server from my back up.

Comment: backup and restore is the easiest and probably best way to do it. It can be done using c# as demonstrated in [this Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852615/sql-server-backuprestore)

Comment: You want to save the database schema which contains the structure.  You can then customize the schema as required for each client.

Comment: You can try to use SQL Server database projects, see [How to use SQL Server Database Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881331/how-to-use-sql-server-database-project)

Comment: if any easy method  of executing all schema by sql code ?

Comment: If you want to create .sql files/statements from a database, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884965/generate-script-for-both-schema-and-data

Comment: is there any programmatic way to restore ? with client given name